# 'dict' object has no attribute 'capitalize'

Tags: python, django, django-views

Straight to the point: when creating a file with **full_content.create** i get the error **'dict' object has no attribute 'capitalize'**.

I use django.forms and inside my **class InputForm** use the method **cleaner_data**. My guess is, when i access the title itself after the cleaning, it's a None.

Util.py:

```
def create_file(title, content):
if default_storage.exists(f"entries/{title}.md"):
    return False
else:
    f = open(f"entries/{title.capitalize()}.md", mode='w+')
    f.write(content)
    f.close()
    return True
```

forms.py:

```
class InputForm(forms.Form):
title = forms.CharField(label="Enter a title")
content = forms.CharField(label="Enter content", widget=forms.Textarea())

def clean_title(self):
    title_name = self.cleaned_data.get("title")
    filename = f"entries/{title_name}.md"
    if not default_storage.exists(filename):
        return self.cleaned_data
    else:
        forms.ValidationError("This title is already taken")
def create(self):
    title = self.cleaned_data["title"]
    content = self.cleaned_data["content"]   
    util.create_file(title, content)
```

views.py:

```
def create(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    full_content = forms.InputForm(request.POST)        
    if full_content.is_valid(): 
        full_content.create()
        #return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html",{
        #        "title": "util.get_page_name(title)",
        #        "entry": "util.get_entry(title)"
        #    })

        return HttpResponse("Test page. What i want is below to output is above")   
return render(request, "encyclopedia/create.html", {
    "title":forms.InputForm()["title"],
    "content":forms.InputForm()["content"]
})
```

Comment: The type of `title` is `dict` and you expect it to be an `str`

Answer (score 0):

The `clean_title` method should return the title. At the moment, you are returning the `cleaned_data` dict. Change it to:

```
def clean_title(self):
    title_name = self.cleaned_data.get("title")
    filename = f"entries/{title_name}.md"
    if not default_storage.exists(filename):
        return title_name
    ...
```

Comment: This works fine. The problem left is with the render from there.
return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html",{
                    "title": util.get_page_name(title),
                    "entry": util.get_entry(title)
                })
Here i get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'capitalize'

Comment: def get_page_name(title):  
    filename = f"entries/{title}.md"
    if default_storage.exists(filename):
        return title.capitalize()
    else:
        return None

Comment: That's a different problem, I can't help you with that there. The traceback is telling you that title is `None`, so you have to figure out why that's happening.